# Modifying BaseController in rails ActiveAdmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, controllers

I am using the ActiveAdmin gem in a rails app.  If I wanted to add a new before filter that applies to all activeadmin gems, how would I do this?  I imagine I could modify the BaseController in ActiveAdmin to achieve this, but what is the proper way to make this modification from within the rails app?  Is there a way to duplicate and overwrite the BaseController?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you , there is a special config for this

```
  # == Controller Filters
  #
  # You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
  # Active Admin resources from here.
  #
   config.before_filter do



   end
```

you can find it in initializers/active_admin.rb

Comment: tried this with .skip_after_filter but got a no method error

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing by writing my code in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` . Just check the line
`#enter code here`

`#Controller Filters`

`# You can add before, after and around filters to all of your`

`# Active Admin resources and pages from here.`

Write down your code here same as described by `Fivell`