# How to define a before_action callback in application controller only for devise_controllers and activeadmin controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, activeadmin

I need to implement a `before_action` callback in my application controller only for activeadmin and devise controllers. For devise controllers I can do something like:

```
before_action :some_callback, if: :devise_controller?
```

How can I do the same for activeadmin controllers? I tried to make a method like:

```
def active_admin_controller?
 if params[:controller] =~ /^admin\//i
   true
 end
end
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to reach the desired result? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Isn’t this what you’re looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180005/modifying-basecontroller-in-rails-activeadmin-gem

Comment: Not exactly. I need to implement a callback in application controller like `before_action :some_callback, unless: :devise_controller? || :active_admin_controller?`. Sorry I didn't mention that there is `unless`, not `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, just had to put the conditions into an array:

```
before_action :some_callback, unless: [:devise_controller?, :active_admin_controller?]
```

also, changed `active_admin_controller?` method:

```
def active_admin_controller?
  if request.filtered_parameters['controller'] =~ /^admin\//i
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for me. Would be nice if it was built into ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was using the `config.skip_*`.

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.before_action :some_callback
end
```